# Как создать коллекцию обьектов в C++?

Tags: c++, winforms, классы, list, коллекции

У меня есть class, нужно создать коллекцию обьектов как в с#, только на с++...

Comment: См. `vector`, например...

Comment: [Containers library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) - выбирай на вкус

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<NameOfClass> vecOfClasses
```

Такой что ли?

если тип созданного объекта

```
NameOfClass*
```

то ты можешь сразу создать vector из этих классов

```
vector<NameOfClass*>vec;
```

но для каждого элемента придется вызывать new, если ты не инициализировал его готовыми объектами напрямую.

то есть:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
vector[i] = new NameOfClass();
}
```